# What do you plug into a socket in the UK?

Tags: meaning, translation

Each electrical gadget, such a lamp (or a hoover), has a part that needs to be plugged into a socket in order to turn it on. This part has two protruding metallic sticks (that fit into the socket). What do you call this thing in the UK?

Comment: Have you tried a bilingual dictionary to answer this? It seems likely that it would be a simple thing to look up.

Comment: It's one of those things. You plug a *plug* into a socket.  Off topic - you call the way you roll a bowling ball down the bowling alley - *bowling* it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We simply call it a 'plug'.

If we need to be more specific, a 'three-pin plug'.

This is because standard UK electrical plugs have 3 pins, the third being an 'earth'.

We also have two-pin plugs in bathrooms for electric razors in the UK. We also call the thing that stops up the drainage in a sink or bath 'a plug', which is why there is sometimes the need to be more specific.

Comment: In North America this is also called a **plug**, and if you really need to differentiate it from other types of plug, you can call it a **cord plug**.

Comment: An image search for _plug top_ will confirm that retailers in several anglophone countries call them plug tops but that usage seems to be confined to electricians, the general public use plugs.

Comment: I've never heard "cord plug" or "plug top" in the UK (although some outlets do seem to use the latter expression - https://www.cef.co.uk/catalogue/products/169597-13a-3-pin-plugtop-white ). I would say "electric plug" if I wanted to distinguish it from sink plugs and bath plugs (although in my experience, confusion is exceedingly rare).

Answer (score 1):

We call them **plugs**  - but in the UK they actually have three **pins**.

https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo/three-pin-plug.html

Comment: A true statement, but it doesn't answer the question. This should have been a comment on the original post.

Comment: @Astralbee - I put the word in bold type to indicate that that is what we call them!

Comment: That isn't clear at all - a 7-word answer will definitely get flagged as 'low quality' by the site's algorithms.